# "Walk" JSON response and populate form fields -- more efficient approach?

Tags: jquery, json

I know there is a far more elegant/efficient way of doing this (in php I would use foreach) but with jQuery how can I walk the var/val pairs of a JSON response and populate form fields with the same id's as the field names in the JSON response?

Here is my JSON response:

```
[{"field":"svendor_name","value":"Vendor Name Inc."},{"field":"svendor_addr1","value":"1234 Vendor Lane."},{"field":"svendor_addr2","value":"Suite 100"},{"field":"svendor_city"
,"value":"Vendorville"},{"field":"svendor_state","value":"CA"},{"field":"svendor_zip","value":"90210"},{"field"
:"svendor_phone","value":"800-555-1234"}]
```

Here is my jQuery code for populating the form:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#svendor_name').bind("change", function()
    {
        var svendor = $("#svendor_name").val();
        svendor = svendor.replace(/&/g, '*');
        $.getJSON("get_vendors.php?sname=" + svendor,
        function(data)
        {
            $.each(data,
                function(i, item)
                {
                    if(item.field == "svendor_name")
                    {
                        $("#svendor_name").val(item.value);
                    }
                    else if(item.field == "svendor_addr1")
                    {
                        $("#svendor_addr1").val(item.value);
                    }
                    else if(item.field == "svendor_addr2")
                    {
                        $("#svendor_addr2").val(item.value);
                    }
                    else if(item.field == "svendor_city")
                    {
                        $("#svendor_city").val(item.value);
                    }
                    else if(item.field == "svendor_state")
                    {
                        $("#svendor_state").val(item.value);
                    }
                    else if(item.field == "svendor_zip")
                    {
                        $("#svendor_zip").val(item.value);
                    }
                    else if(item.field == "svendor_phone")
                    {
                        $("#svendor_phone").val(item.value);
                    }
                    else if(item.field == "svendor_id")
                    {
                        $("#svendor_id").val(item.value);
                    }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

That all works fine and good but I really want to avoid all the if/else statements and just use the data coming back from the getJSON method to determine what fields get populated with what values.  What is a cleaner/more effective approach to this?

-- Nicholas

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get rid of all "if" statements by replacing your $.each with this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item){
  $("#"+item.field).val(item.value);
});
```

Comment: Excellent response. Works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: This works fine as long as all the fields are input fields. But what about combo boxes, checkboxes and radio buttons? Isn't there a good plugin that takes care of this?

Comment: Yeah, combos, checkboxes and radio buttons can be a pain on such situations.
For radio buttons and checkboxes, here's a good enough solution: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898883/jquery-ajax-parse-xml-and-set-radiobutton

Answer (score 8):

What is wrong with this?

```
$.each(data,
    function(i, item) {
        $("#" + item.field).val(item.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does not behave well for checkboxes and radio buttons

Answer (score 3):

If your results looks like this:

```
[{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}]
```

Then the code provided by Seb and Chetan works

```
$.each(data, function(i, item){
  $("#"+item.field).val(item.value);
});
```

If your results looks like this:

```
{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}
```

Then use this code

```
$.each(data, function(field, value){
  $("#"+field).val(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that element IDs are the same as fields in your JSON, how about:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#svendor_name').bind("change", function()
    {
        var svendor = $("#svendor_name").val();
        svendor = svendor.replace(/&/g, '*');
        $.getJSON("get_vendors.php?sname=" + svendor,
        function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    $('#' + item.field).val(item.value);
                });
        });
    });
});
```