# Jquery-ajax parse xml and set radiobutton

Tags: xml, jquery, radio-button

I've a form with some radio button like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="leva" value="a"><input type="radio" name="leva" value="b">
```

with ajax post method I receive value of the radio.
The question is how can I set correct radio value to checked?

thanks in advance
ciao
h.

Comment: i didnt got your question much, but if you have got your value it might have been recieved as leva[0],leva[1] etc

Answer (score 4):

You just need to find the right button using an [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for the value, then set `checked` attribute using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), like this:

```
$("input:radio[name='leva'][value='"+ returnedValue +"']").attr('checked', true);
```

The browser will handle un-selecting the other options since it's a radio button, and if no button is found with the `value`...well, like all jQuery selectors, it just won't have any effect, which is usually what's desired.

Comment: You may want to throw in `[name='leva']` too, to make sure you don't check radio buttons on other groups.

Comment: @Kobi - fair point, better to make it as precise as possible, updated.