# Ajax populate form from mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to populate a form using Ajax.

To accomplish this I am following a guide from http://www.crackajax.net/popform.php

However, it does not seem to work for me. Here is the code:

My form.html:

```
<tbody>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="barcode">barcode</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="barcode" name="product[barcode]" type="text" onKeyUp="getagentids();">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="traccategory">Array</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="traccategory" name="product[traccategory]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_model">model</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_model" name="product[trac_model]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_serial">serial</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_serial" name="product[trac_serial]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_proctype">proctype</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_proctype" name="product[trac_proctype]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_hdd">trac_hdd</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_hdd" name="product[trac_hdd]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_type">trac_type</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_type" name="product[trac_type]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_cond">trac_cond</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_cond" name="product[trac_cond]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_drive">trac_drive</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_drive" name="product[trac_drive]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_os">trac_os</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_os" name="product[trac_os]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_cpu">trac_cpu</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_cpu" name="product[trac_cpu]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_ram">trac_ram</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_ram" name="product[trac_ram]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_manu">trac_manu</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_manu" name="product[trac_manu]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_testedby">trac_testedby</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_testedby" name="product[trac_testedby]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

            </tbody>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest; // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
try{
// Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
// Internet Explorer Browsers
try{
ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
try{
ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e){
// Something went wrong
alert("Your browser broke!");
return false;
}
}
}

 var url = "getdata.php?param=";
function getagentids() {
var idValue = document.getElementById("barcode").value;
var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random()*99999999); // cache buster
http.open("GET", url + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true);
http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
http.send(null);
function handleHttpResponse() {
if (http.readyState == 4) {
results = http.responseText.split(",");

locument.getElementById('barcode').value = results[1];
document.getElementById('model').value = results[2];
document.getElementById('serial').value = results[3];
document.getElementById('proctype').value = results[4];

document.getElementById('trac_hdd').value = results[5];
document.getElementById('trac_type').value = results[6];
document.getElementById('trac_cond').value = results[7];
document.getElementById('trac_drive').value = results[8];
document.getElementById('trac_os').value = results[9];
document.getElementById('trac_cpu').value = results[10];
document.getElementById('trac_ram').value = results[11];
document.getElementById('trac_manu').value = results[12];
document.getElementById('trac_testedby').value = results[13];

}
}
var idValue = document.getElementById("barcode").value;
var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random()*99999999); // cache buster
ajaxDisplay.open("GET", "getdata.php" + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
//-->
</script>
```

And finally my getdata.php looks like this.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "testest");
    if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("pos", $con);
    if (strlen($param) > 0) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT
    category.short_description AS category,
    asset.asset_code AS code,
    asset_model_number.short_description AS model,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_1 AS mnfserial,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_6 AS proctype,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_7 AS hdd,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_8 AS type,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_9 AS cond,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_10 AS drive,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_12 AS os,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_13 AS cpu,
    asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_14 AS ram,
    manufacturer.short_description AS Manu,
    user_account.username AS testedby,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
    asset_transaction
LEFT JOIN asset
  ON asset_transaction.asset_id = asset.asset_id
LEFT JOIN asset_model
  ON asset.asset_model_id = asset_model.asset_model_id
LEFT JOIN asset_model_number
  ON asset.asset_model_number_id = asset_model_number.asset_model_number_id
LEFT JOIN asset_custom_field_helper
  ON asset.asset_id = asset_custom_field_helper.asset_id
LEFT JOIN user_account
  ON asset.created_by = user_account.user_account_id
LEFT JOIN category
  ON asset_model.category_id = category.category_id
LEFT JOIN manufacturer
  ON asset_model.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.manufacturer_id


WHERE asset.asset_code LIKE '$param%'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $category = $myrow["category"];
    $code = $myrow["code"];
    $model = $myrow["model"];
    $mnfserial = $myrow["mnfserial"];
    $proctype = $myrow["proctype"];
    $hdd = $myrow["hdd"];
    $drive = $myrow["drive"];
    $os = $myrow["os"];
    $cpu = $myrow["cpu"];
    $ram = $myrow["ram"];
    $manu = $myrow["Manu"];
    $testedby = $myrow["testedby"];

    $textout .= $category . "," . $code . "," . $model . "," . $mnfserial . "," . $proctype . "," . $hdd . "," . $type . "," . $cond . "," . $drive . "," . $os . "," . $cpu . "," . $ram . "," . $manu . "," . $testedby;
    }
    } else {
    $textout = " , , ," . $param;
    }
    }
    echo $textout;
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Now the problem is that I don't get any errors but this code does not work.
I want to populate the above html table form when first barcode is entered.

Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: I would first recommend reading jQuery tutorial get some time to understand it than read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635565/walk-json-response-and-populate-form-fields-more-efficient-approach  , read about using JSON in PHP ,  your code will shrink 80% and you will get learn faster and use less time to develop apps . Also change PHP part to use less complex sql so you can easily grasp basics, Than when you have a spcific problem ask specific question.

Comment: Too be honest I am not a developer and I just want this thing to work, please can you help?

Comment: BojanT, Please can you help me achieve what I explained above?

Comment: Sorry, I would do this completely the other way, and as you are not a developer it wont help , as you would need to change a code to suite your needs.

Comment: Thank you Bojan, I have managed to fix the script see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix this problem, let me explain what was wrong.

My getdata.php was not right, I was trying to access "param" variables which was not defined correctly. So I defined as a variable .

```
$param = $_GET["param"];
```

So here is the complete getdata.php code I used to fix it.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
          if (!$con) {
             die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                     }
$param = $_GET["param"];

    mysql_select_db("pos", $con);
          if (strlen($param) > 0) {
               $result = mysql_query("SELECT
               category.short_description AS category,
               asset.asset_code AS code,
               asset_model_number.short_description AS model,
               asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_1 AS mnfserial,
               asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_6 AS proctype,
               asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_7 AS hdd,
               asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_8 AS type,
               asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_9 AS cond,
               asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_10 AS drive,
               asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_12 AS os,
               asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_13 AS cpu,
               asset_custom_field_helper.cfv_14 AS ram,
               manufacturer.short_description AS Manu,
               user_account.username AS testedby
          FROM
               asset_transaction
               LEFT JOIN asset
               ON asset_transaction.asset_id = asset.asset_id
               LEFT JOIN asset_model
               ON asset.asset_model_id = asset_model.asset_model_id
               LEFT JOIN asset_model_number
               ON asset.asset_model_number_id =  
               asset_model_number.asset_model_number_id
               LEFT JOIN asset_custom_field_helper
               ON asset.asset_id = asset_custom_field_helper.asset_id
               LEFT JOIN user_account
               ON asset.created_by = user_account.user_account_id
               LEFT JOIN category
               ON asset_model.category_id = category.category_id
               LEFT JOIN manufacturer
               ON asset_model.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.manufacturer_id


WHERE asset.asset_code LIKE '$param%' limit 1");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $category = $myrow["category"];
    $code = $myrow["code"];
    $model = $myrow["model"];
    $mnfserial = $myrow["mnfserial"];
    $proctype = $myrow["proctype"];
    $hdd = $myrow["hdd"];
    $type = $myrow["type"];
    $cond = $myrow["cond"];
    $drive = $myrow["drive"];
    $os = $myrow["os"];
    $cpu = $myrow["cpu"];
    $ram = $myrow["ram"];
    $manu = $myrow["Manu"];
    $testedby = $myrow["testedby"];

    $textout .= $code . "," . $category . "," . $model . "," . $mnfserial . "," . $proctype . "," . $hdd . "," . $type . "," . $cond . "," . $drive . "," . $os . "," . $cpu . "," . $ram . "," . $manu . "," . $testedby;
    }
    } else {
    $textout = ", , , , , , , , , , , , , " . $param;
    }
    }
    echo $textout;
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

And here is the javascript to process AJAX data.

```
<script>
var url = "/getdata.php?param=";
function handleHttpResponse() {
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
         results = http.responseText.split(",");

document.getElementById('barcode').value = results[0];
document.getElementById('trac_model').value = results[2];
document.getElementById('trac_serial').value = results[3];
document.getElementById('trac_proctype').value = results[4];
document.getElementById('trac_hdd').value = results[5];
document.getElementById('trac_type').value = results[6];
document.getElementById('trac_cond').value = results[7];
document.getElementById('trac_drive').value = results[8];
document.getElementById('trac_os').value = results[9];
document.getElementById('trac_cpu').value = results[10];
document.getElementById('trac_ram').value = results[11];
document.getElementById('trac_manu').value = results[12];
document.getElementById('trac_testedby').value = results[13];
document.getElementById('traccategory').value = results[1];

document.getElementById('name').value = results[12] +" "+ results[1] +" "+ results[2] +", "+ results[11] + " RAM, " + results[10] + " Ghz , " + results[4] +" Processor, "+ results[5] +" HDD, Powerful Machine" ;

}
}
 function getagentids() {
        var idValue = document.getElementById("coda").value;
        var myRandom=parseInt(Math.random()*99999999);  // cache buster
        http.open("GET", url + escape(idValue) + "&amp;rand=" + myRandom, true);
        http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
        http.send(null);
        }


function getHTTPObject() {
        var xmlhttp;
        /*@cc_on
         @if (@_jscript_version &gt;= 5)
          try {
              xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
              } catch (e) {
              try {
                  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  } catch (E) {
                  xmlhttp = false;
                  }
              }
         @else
          xmlhttp = false;
         @end @*/
        if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
         try {
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           } catch (e) {
           xmlhttp = false;
           }
          }
          return xmlhttp;
        }


var http = getHTTPObject(); // We create the HTTP Object

  </script>
```

Then in the same file as javascript above I have a form which is used to input barcode to pull the data from the database. Here is the form.

```
<form name="schform"> <table>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="barcode">Enter your Asset Barcode to Pull the data from Inventory System</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="coda" name="coda" type="text" onKeyUp="getagentids();">            </td>
    </tr>
</tr> </table> </form>
```

Then the form in the same file as above I want to populate.

```
<tbody>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="barcode">barcode</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="barcode" name="product[barcode]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="traccategory">Array</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="traccategory" name="product[traccategory]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_model">model</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_model" name="product[trac_model]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_serial">serial</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_serial" name="product[trac_serial]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_proctype">proctype</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_proctype" name="product[trac_proctype]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_hdd">trac_hdd</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_hdd" name="product[trac_hdd]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_type">trac_type</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_type" name="product[trac_type]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_cond">trac_cond</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_cond" name="product[trac_cond]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_drive">trac_drive</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_drive" name="product[trac_drive]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_os">trac_os</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_os" name="product[trac_os]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_cpu">trac_cpu</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_cpu" name="product[trac_cpu]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_ram">trac_ram</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_ram" name="product[trac_ram]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_manu">trac_manu</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_manu" name="product[trac_manu]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="trac_testedby">trac_testedby</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <input id="trac_testedby" name="product[trac_testedby]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">            </td>
    </tr>

            </tbody>
```

Now let me show you the screenshot how it looks, notice the "Enter your Asset Barcode to Pull the data from Inventory System. It is currently empty / blank.

[image]

Now let me put a barcode in to see if it auto populate the form.

[image]